# Struggling to animate a div into view using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to reveal a div using css animations when I click a link but it isn't working. Can anyone help?

Here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/SSsVx/36/

```
<div id="submit-logged-out">
    foo
</div>

<a href="#"> run</a>

$("a").click(function(){
      $('#submit-logged-out').addClass('popout');
});

#submit-logged-out {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
    width:80%;
    opacity:0;
}
    .popout {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-animation: popout 2.25s ease;
        -moz-animation: popout 2.25s ease;
        -ms-animation: popout 2.25s ease;
        -o-animation: popout 2.25s ease;
        animation: popout 2.25s ease;
    }

    /* add all the rest*/
    @-webkit-keyframes popout {
        0%{-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
        80%{-webkit-transform:scale(1.05)}
        100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
    }

    @-moz-keyframes popout {
        0%{-moz-transform:scale(0)}
        80%{-moz-transform:scale(1.05)}
        100%{-moz-transform:scale(1)}
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a matter of IDs having higher priorities than classes in CSS. So your opacity is never fetched from the popout class but uses the one from the ID (which is zero). Technically, your animations are working, but you can't see them.

To fix this, just change the CSS rule from `.popout` to  `#submit-logged-out.popout` and it should work.

So, this:

```
.popout {
...
}
```

should be this:

```
#submit-logged-out.popout {
...
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SSsVx/38/

Comment: I never knew id's have a higher priority. What to do it the id is unknown?

Comment: Nothing, your original code would work as the popout class rules would take over. You can test this by changing the id to a class (`#submit-logged-out` to `.submit-logged-out`, and on the element as well, of course). See here: http://jsfiddle.net/SSsVx/39/

Comment: You're welcome! It's also worth knowing that more specific selectors have higher priority than less specific ones: so, rules from `div .popout` would override those from just `.popout`. If the priority is the same (like in the example 39 I gave you above: `.class1` vs `.class2` on the same element), they go by order - those that come later in the code override the previous ones. See how these guys work: http://jsfiddle.net/L7Btu/